# Swift LocalSearchCompleter Not being fired

Tags: swift, xcode, mapkit, swiftui, swift5

I have this class which conforms to MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate. I have also implemented `completerDidUpdateResults`. I'm using SwiftUI so no view controllers here. I'm trying to put the whole logic at a service.

when I try to call `completer.queryFragment = "be"` nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class LocalSearchCompleterService: NSObject, MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate {
    let completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter = MKLocalSearchCompleter()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        completer.delegate = self
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 47.5596, longitude: 7.5886)
        completer.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, latitudinalMeters: 10000, longitudinalMeters: 10000)
    }

    func completerDidUpdateResults(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter) {
        print("called")
        let addresses = completer.results.map { result in
            result.title + ", " + result.subtitle
        }

        print(addresses)
    }

    func autocomplete() {
        completer.queryFragment = "be"
    }

}
```

and then I call it from outside: `LocalSearchCompleterService().autocomplete()`
Nothing happens in the console

What am i missing?

Comment: Where do you init the service?

Comment: when I call the method: `LocalSearchCompleterService().autocomplete()`

Comment: thanks. It was ok I just had to do var localSearchCompleterService = LocalSearchCompleterService() and then .autocomplete() but ... why I mean isn't it the same?

Comment: autocomplete() is it requested from the delegate? if not you should call it otherwise it does not triggers automatically. Otherwise there is a problem on where you are storing the service